# RegEx NPP - Need some assistance with a lookaround

Tags: regex, notepad++

In NPP, I am attempting a search/replace to turn a broken line back into a single line of text. (This will be used often)

However, when I search/replace in Notepad++, it removes the entire first line. Clearly I am doing something wrong with my look-around.

[Regex101 fiddle to work with.](https://regex101.com/r/jMHAqS/3)

```
50TH-ST-TA5000-1#sh in efm-g 1/11/4
  Alias                           : EZE-P SCHOENFELD ASSET                     
  Provisioned Links               : 11/5,    11/6,    11/30,   11/31,   
                                    13/1,    13/2                       
  Active Links                    : 11/5,    13/2                       
  Inhibited Links                 : None                                
                                   Upstream               Downstream
  Rate                       kbps : 6400                   6400
```

Comment: besides the fact there is no lookaround in your regex, what are your using for substitution? there is no `\1` replacement in your regex101

Comment: Is [**this**](https://regex101.com/r/jMHAqS/2) what you're looking for?

Comment: Hi Jan, that deleted the first line also (try it in Notepad++). @ᴳᵁᴵᴰᴼ I tried so many things, I must have missed that in the copy/paste - I'll add the look-around I used. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You went too complex way. Please try this:

find: `,\s+[\r\n]+\s+`

replace: `,---` (comma and 3 spaces)

Comment: Thanks Kosh. I got almost what I was looking for with a slight modification: `(?<=,)\s+[\r\n]+\s+` - and then I only needed to add back the spaces *(i.e. replace with three spaces)*

Comment: @crashwap, Great! Happy to help! However lookbehind variant is more expensive in resources J.